# Compiler optimization for variable declaration location

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I read from [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/declare-near-first-use.html) that "Locals should be declared near their first use". Also Scott Meyer's Effective C++ Item 26 also suggests it for performance reasons. But I recently happened to hear from someone that compilers are smart enough to optimize variables where ever they are defined irrespective of the scope they are actually used within a function. And he suggests to declare the variable at the top of the function for ease of understanding(i dont buy this reason though). Is he correct regarding the compiler optimization?

(The question is regarding performance and compiler optimization. Not code readability).

Comment: That advice from the FAQ is to enhance readability. It's for the humans advantage and not the compilers

Comment: @DeadMG edited the question. hope its clear now.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler has nothing to do with it.  There are two general rules
with regards to defining variables (local or others): keep the scope and
visibility as small as possible, and if at all possible, initialize in
the definition.  These rules are for human readers, not the compiler.
And both do lead to "declaring locals near their first use", as a
corollary.

Comment: do you mean there are no performance benefits with variables (with constructurs/destructors) declared in a more local scope (i.e, in an inner code block within a function)? Will the compiler intelligently call constructor within the inner code block where it used even if declared at the top of the function block?

Comment: @nariknahom The compiler cannot change where the constructor or destructor is called; this is defined by the language.  Typically (but there are significant exceptions, especially where RAII is involved), this won't make any real difference.  (With something like a `scoped_lock`, you don't really want the compiler changing where the destructor is called, do you?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are smart enough.

But there is also a software technical answer: You should do it because it's a better programming style.

Answer (score 0):

Putting variable declaration near where the variables are used increases locality, and can make the code and program flow easier to understand. Also, if a variable is placed in a nested scope then it will be "destructed" when leaving the scope it was declared in, helping with things like RAII.

Answer (score 0):

You should always strive write a source code which is easy to read understand and comprehend.

Even if the compilers are able to optimize this it is a good practice to do still do it. It provides you with **improved readability**, You do not need to cache and remember what value a variable was initialized to at the begining of the block.